# Python: How to pull a 'fake' modeled date from a dataframe header string and turn it into a new column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm working with a list of ~60k files that are modeled years that range from the year 1-59000. Each of those 60k files is in the following structure (numbers used are examples):

```
storm12345 10/6/ 48365

100

7463,75

7464,80

.
.
.
```

And so on, of varying lengths. The first two rows are info about the dataframe, but I specifically need to recognize and retain the 'year', in this example 48365, so I can go back and assign this whole file as that year, preferably making an entire new column labeled 'year' that is the year shown at the beginning of the file and do this for all 60k files for their respective years.

Final product looking something like this:

```
storm12345 10/6/ 48365

100

A, B, year

7463,75,48365

7464,80,48365

.
.
.
```

And so on, where the final column is the year

As a bonus, I also need to label the columns A and B, however when I use `pd.read_csv` and specify `header=[0,1]`, I am no longer able to name those columns and receive the following error:

> ValueError: cannot specify names when specifying a multi-index header

Thank you!

Comment: May you provide more files' first 2 lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read files with `sep='\n'`, so the DataFrame only contains one column.

Then assign the first line and second line to lable the file.

finally, split the column. and dropna.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\n', header=None, dtype=str)

df['line_1st'] = df.iloc[0, 0]
df['line_2nd'] = df.iloc[1, 0]

df['year'] = df['line_1st'].str.extract(' (\d+)$')
df[['A', 'B']] = df[0].str.split(',', n=1, expand=True).values

cols = ['A', 'B', 'year','line_1st', 'line_2nd']
dfn = df.dropna()[cols]

print(dfn)

         A   B   year                line_1st line_2nd
    2  7463  75  48365  storm12345 10/6/ 48365      100
    3  7464  80  48365  storm12345 10/6/ 48365      100
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great on my personal machine, then when I transfer the same code over to a remote server with the same code/data, I receive the  following error:

KeyError: "None of [Index(['A,B'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Any idea why this would occur only via that server, yet work fine elsewhere?

Comment: you could check the content of the file and the shape of `df.dropna().shape` when the error occurs。 May be the file does not contain lines with comma.